# Trouble making http request from lighttpd server to pm2 server

Tags: http, raspberry-pi, pm2, lighttpd

**Background:**

I have my personal website running on a lighttpd server on my raspberry pi. I have that server’s port (80) forwarded so it can be accessed publicly.

I’m in the process of making a project, and I want a node.js service to make requests to from the lighttpd server. I set up pm2 so the node.js server is always running. I have that port forwarded too (5000). I've verified that this server is working via postman and the browser

**Problem:**

I'm receiving the following error when making requests:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `private`.

Of note; I have `Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network:true` in the response header and `Access-Control-Request-Private-Network:true` in the request header. The only other solution I've found that might fix this is getting an SSL cert for the lighttpd server and using https for it, however I'm struggling setting that up to see if it would work

**Questions:**

- 1. Would getting an SSL cert for lighttpd allow me to make requests to my pm2 server?
- 2. Is there a different solution?
- 3. How secure is this setup? I don't expect a lot of traffic...

Comment: Setting up TLS with lighttpd: https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_SSL#Quick-Start and https://wiki.lighttpd.net/HowToSimpleSSL

Comment: I was able to set up SSL on my lighttpd server, but still unable to make requests publicly. I realized my issue is that I'm trying to use multiple ports for separate domains, and you can't really do that. The best solution I've found is to set up a reverse proxy and use subdomains. Like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1035991/setting-up-sub-domains-to-access-different-ports-on-specific-ip